# Fix the header of html table at top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, tableheader

I have fixed the columns of html table as given in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/pgosxkrm/1/). Same way I am trying to fix only the header row of table as,

```
var $table = $('.table');
var $fixedColumn = $table.clone().insertBefore($table).addClass('fixed-column');

$fixedColumn.find('tbody').remove();

$fixedColumn.find('thead th').each(function (i, elem) {
    $(this).width($table.find('tbody tr:first td:eq(' + i + ')').width());
});
```

which is given in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/pgosxkrm/7/). But the header didn't fixed. What is missing?

Comment: What is it supposed to fix? All the column headings are the same width as the corresponding columns in the body, so nothing happens.

Comment: As in first fiddle, the first 3 columns are freezed, I want to fix the header freezed in second fiddle when scrolling vertically.

Comment: Just only put your "overflow-y:scroll" in your <tbody> tag. Not in your whole table.

Answer (score 1):

How about this??

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/pgosxkrm/8/)**

```
   <tr class="fixed">
       <th>#</th>
       <th>Table heading</th>
       <th>Table heading</th>
       <th>Table heading</th>
       <th>Table heading</th>
       <th>Table heading</th>
       <th>Table heading</th>
   </tr>
```

**css**

```
.fixed
{
    position:fixed;
    background:gray;

}
```

You can try this **[EXAMPLE](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/01/09/sticky-table-headers-columns/)** too if you are much more interested!!